# Know if user is authorized in Session_Start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, windows-authentication

I am using `MVC 5` with windows authentication. And I am using `AuthorizeAttribute` to allow specific Roles.

I need to log login, logoff and unsuccessful login.

I use `Session_Start` and `Session_End` for logging login and logoff. And `Application_EndRequest` with checking

```
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Status.StartsWith("401"))
```

for unsuccessful login.

Problem is when there is unsuccessful login I also log login and logoff because I don't know if user is authorized in `Session_Start` or `Session_End`.

Is there any way to find out if user is authorized in `Session_Start` and `Session_End`. Or is there better solution to log this information?
Thank You..

Comment: That logic belongs to your login, logoff modules not the Session_Start and Session_End.

Comment: I use windows authentication .. so there is no modules in my code for this.

Comment: Didn't notice its a windows auth. My bad